# Getting data from object Id in Parse.com

Tags: java, android, parsing, parse-platform

I am facing some problem related to parse.com
I want to fetch the data for a perticular objectId...I have used following code to get the data but seems it is depreciated..as it returned following exception

```
no results found for query
```

I have used following code to get the data form objectId:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("User");
    query.getInBackground("U8mCwTHOaC", new GetCallback() {
      public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            Log.d(">>>", "0000>>>" +objid);
        dlg.dismiss();
        if (e == null) {
          // object will be your game score
             Log.d(">>",">>"+object);
        } else {
          // something went wrong
             Log.d(">>",">>"+e);
        }
      }
    });
```

Here "U8mCwTHOaC"  is my objectId,I want to fetch the row of this objectId.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to get data from user table.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
    query.whereEqualTo("objectId","U8mCwTHOaC");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // row of Object Id "U8mCwTHOaC"
            } else {
                // error
            }
        }
    });
```

if you want the row of current user

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
    query.whereEqualTo("objectId",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // row of Object Id "Current USer"
            } else {
                // error
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..according to my requirement I have used your first solution ,but It is not working ..It returned list size 0.

Comment: Check your user table whether it has the corresponding ObjectId entry..and use "_User" instead of "User" in Query

Comment: don't know..why It is used "_User" in the place of "User"..but it worked.thanks