# get ObjectID from ParseUser's via email

Tags: android, parse-platform

there
I want use Parse Query to get objectID (not current user), and then user objectID to get profile img from ParseUser

```
 ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
        userQuery.whereEqualTo("username",name);
        userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> results, ParseException e) {
                // results has the list of users with a hometown team with a losing record
                String testObjectID =results.get().getObjectId();
                    Log.d("score", testObjectID.toString());
            }
        });
```

in the code I mention above, I want find the User email to get ObjectID,
but there need get(int position), what can I do is get email account position to get the ObjectID?

```
String testObjectID =results.get(0).getObjectId();
```

by the other way, also not work for me...
  object always null...

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
    query.whereEqualTo("username",name);
    Log.d("score name", name);
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (object == null) {
                Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed."+e.toString());
            } else {

                String testObjectID = object.getObjectId();
                Log.d("score", testObjectID.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

log

```
04-20 10:09:03.301  15623-15623/com.di D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x52937000 size:4096
04-20 10:09:03.311  15623-15623/com.di D/score name﹕ a2@msn.com
04-20 10:09:03.321  15623-15623/com.di D/score﹕ Retrieved a2@msn.com scores
04-20 10:09:03.701  15623-15623/com.di D/score testObjectID﹕ The getFirst request failed.com.parse.ParseException: no results found for query
04-20 10:09:03.971  15623-15623/com.di D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x577fa000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:74
04-20 10:09:03.971  15623-15623/com.di D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x50ae1000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:82
```

please help, thanks

Comment: Is there an exception logged?  Have you verified that the `name` argument is correct and matches a user in the database?

Comment: yes, it's correct and  match the user mail,
it get from the other class print log with Retrieved a2@msn.com scores

Comment: I figure it out, thanks @nasch reply!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve it, need use a loop on List

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
userQuery.whereEqualTo("username",name);
userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    public void done(List<ParseUser> results, ParseException e) {
        // results has the list of users with a hometown team with a losing record
        for (int j=0 ; j< results.size(); j++) {
            String testObjectID = results.get(j).getObjectId();
            Log.d("score testObjectID", testObjectID.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

and I got the point with Query method need "_user"
[Getting data from object Id in Parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622991/getting-data-from-object-id-in-parse-com)