# Parse server cloud code getting and updating an object

Tags: javascript, swift, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

When a user shares a post I want to be able to give them a reward point for doing so. I am calling the cloud function from xcode like this.

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "shares", withParameters: ["objectID" : "z2pU3UDFrh"])
```

I hardcoded an object id for now just to check if its working. 
Here is my cloud code function that gets called

```
  Parse.Cloud.define("shares", function(request, response) {

    var shareQuery = new Parse.Query("Parse.POSTS");
    shareQuery.get(request.params.objectID, {
      success: function(object) {
        console.log(object)
        object.increment("score");
        object.save();
      },
      error: function(error) { },
      useMasterKey: true
    });

  });
```

when I check the logs it prints  "undefined" and the score remains unchanged

Comment: How is the table named ? `POSTS` (as a convention, you should use camel-case) ?

Comment: yes it is named POSTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `var shareQuery = new Parse.Query("Parse.POSTS");`
 with 
`var shareQuery = new Parse.Query("POSTS");`

```
Parse.Cloud.define("shares", function(request, response) {

    var shareQuery = new Parse.Query("POSTS");
    shareQuery.get(request.params.objectID, {
      success: function(object) {
        console.log(object)
        object.increment("score");
        object.save();
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.error(error)
      },
      useMasterKey: true
    });

  });
```

Comment: this seems to have worked, but i am now getting an error in the logs saying object not found when in fact there exists and object with that objectId

Comment: Enable VERBOSE mode, it might help out getting to the bottom of the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622991/getting-data-from-object-id-in-parse-com   u are missing .whereEqualTo   see accepted ans at the link

Comment: `get( objectId, options )`  is provided by the JS SDK when the `objectId` is known. http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_get. Shouldn't need equalsTo

Comment: another try.  if you are getting response=empyset instead of object you should check the ACL on the POSTS objects.  If the query submitted by user without permissions on POSTS then nothing returned by the query

Comment: @RobertRowntree I believe the acl is causing the issue - is it possible to fix this without giving public write access

Comment: a GET on an obj in POSTS that  exists but is not actually retreived would be due to null READ permissions in the ACL.. u may need to read more on the ACL security implementation. ususually , on a create you grant PUBLIC READ in the ACL and then world can read the object.

Comment: By default the read access on the objects seem to be public read access, only when I change them to public write access does the cloud code function actually increment the number