# Update Parse user via Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to update some attributes on my user via cloud code, but even when there is no error, nothing is being updated??? Any thoughts?

Parse.Cloud.define("updateDetailsUser", function (request, response) {

```
var query = new Parse.Query("User");
query.equalTo("objectId", request.user.id);
var mobileNumber = request.params.mobileNumber;
var fullName = request.params.fullName;
var email = request.params.email;
query.first({
    success: function (user) {
        user.set("mobileNumber", mobileNumber);
        user.set("fullName", fullName);
        user.set("email", email);
       user.save(null, {
            useMasterKey: true,
            success: function (updated) {

            }
        });
    }

});
```

});

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622991/getting-data-from-object-id-in-parse-com  try "_User" as in link accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

For all the classes that are built-in, it suggests to use the Parse class name for them. In case of `User`, you need to use `Parse.User`.

So, to fix this, just replace
`var query = new Parse.Query("User");` with `var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);` and it should work.

To read further : http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/